# VBA to look up value in table and copy formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I have a two column look up table. Column 1 is a fixed list of items and column 2 has a formula in it.

In another table when someone enters data in say cell a1 and it matches an item in column 1 of my look up table I need the corresponding formula from column 2 copied and pasted into cell b2.

Lots of google searching trying to find a way for VLOOKUP to copy formula in lieu of cell value has returned nothing so I assume the only way to do it is via VBA?

Comment: do you want to display the formula or to calculate the result try `INDIRECT()`

Comment: I would like to calculate the result of the formula

Comment: then try with `INDIRECT` combined with `VLOOKUP` and show us where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This small sample assumes the data is in columns **C** and **D:**

```
Sub Matt()
    Dim r As Range, Tabl As Range
    Set Tabl = Range("C1:C1000")
    Set r = Tabl.Find(What:=Range("A1").Value, After:=Tabl(1))
    Range("B1").Formula = r.Offset(0, 1).Formula
End Sub
```

place a value in **A1** and run the macro

**EDIT#1:**

This version will loop down column **A**

```
Sub Matt_The_Sequel()
    Dim r As Range, Tabl As Range, N As Long
    Set Tabl = Range("C1:C1000")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Set r = Tabl.Find(What:=Range("A" & i).Value, After:=Tabl(1))
        Range("B" & i).Formula = r.Offset(0, 1).Formula
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

```
Sub Matt_The_Sequel2()
    Dim r As Range, Tabl As Range, N As Long
    Dim First_Row As Long
    Set Tabl = Range("C1:C1000")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    First_Row = 4


    For i = First_Row To N
        Set r = Tabl.Find(What:=Range("A" & i).Value, After:=Tabl(1))
        Range("B" & i).Formula = r.Offset(0, 1).Formula
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That is perfect however one last request, how would I loop it to repeat in cells B2, B3 etc so long as there is an entry in A2, A3 etc?

Comment: Sorry one last one... what if I want to off set the start, eg: instead of A1 i want the loop to begin at A4 as I have a couple rows of headings etc? Thanks for your help by the way!